# How to load more content with Angular (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I'm newbie on AngularJS, and now, I'm trying to create simplest web-app, that load some JSON data from server.
It works fine for now, looks like this:

JS FILE

```
app.controller('myCont', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.moreItems = function() {
        $http.post('php/index.php').
            success(function (data) {
                $scope.posts = data;
            }
        );

        console.log('Button work');
    }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCont">  
    <span ng-click="moreItems()">Load more</span>  
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="some in something">{{some.here}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

PHP generates some JSON for that page. Every time it gives me different data.
But my trouble is that I have no idea how to load MORE data to that controller. It always replaces it, but I want to concat it.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the data is retrieved from your PHP server your code is overwritting the $scope.posts variable. Assuming your $scope.posts var is an object and you want to add new posts to it when you call `moreItems()` since concatenate two objects in javascript is a very common task and in order to not reinvent the wheel, I encourage you to use the `_.extend` function of underscore.js library or similar and go

```js
app.controller('myCont', ['$scope', '$http'], function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.moreItems = function()
    {
    $http.post('php/index.php').
        success(function (data)
        {
            _.extend($scope.posts, data);
        }
    );

    console.log('Button work');
});
```

http://underscorejs.org/#extend
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: Hi. Thanks for respond! I include underscode.js and update the JS code  but in my case it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **angular.extend** to concatenate your data. Whenever the JSON data will be retrieved, it will get concatenated with the previous data in same JSON object.

Note: If the new incoming data is consisting the same properties as that of previous JSON object then those will get override with the new data. Be sure incoming data consists different properties if you want to store the old data of properties.

```
app.controller('myCont', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.moreItems = function()
    {
        $http.post('php/index.php').
            success(function (data) 
                {                       
                    angular.extend($scope.posts, data)
                }
        );

        console.log('Button work');
    }
}]);
```

Additional Info:  If you want to store the previous data of properties then you can use browser local storage to add and retrive data. That will save you from making multiple DB call.

Adding Data :

```
localStorageService.add("postsData", JSON.stringify($scope.posts));
```

Retriveing Data :

```
$scope.posts = localStorageService.get("postsData");
```

*For more info on browserlocalstorage do let me know......*

Comment: I think you have to remove the `$scope.posts = {}`. Now you're clearing `$scope.posts` and adding new things to it, so it won't keep your existing data. Correct me if I'm wrong :-).